# How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?

Tags: bash

I've renamed some files in a fairly large project and want to remove the .pyc files they've left behind. I tried the bash script:

```
 rm -r *.pyc
```

But that doesn't recurse through the folders as I thought it would. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work because in UNIX, globs are expanded by the shell, not by the program being run.  If you have a.pyc and b.pyc in the current directory, and directories foo and bar, `rm` will be called with arguments [-r, a.pyc, b.pyc].

Comment: if you are worrying about pushing your code to other people, you can just add it to the .gitignore
`**/*.pyc`
then you won't have to worry about it again

Answer (score 1294, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I tested both of these. The directories were probably too small to be significant, but this came out faster than mine, which is what I expected since mine has to assemble the list and then iterate through it, while yours removes each item as it is found.

Comment: Find has a builtin "-delete" action, so you could do just `find . -name \*.pyc -delete`

Comment: Most importantly, if this is a dev machine, you can set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=True, and you'll never need to do this again. See: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files/154617#154617).

Comment: You are not quoting `{}`. What would happen if accidentally word-split and deleted an intermediate path which happens to be called like a fragment of the path you found?

Comment: in my .bashrc: `alias rmPyCrap="find . -name \*.pyc -delete && find . -type d -name __pycache__ -delete"`

Comment: `-delete` is not part of the POSIX specification, and not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of `find`.

Comment: If you are scared - which might be good - make a first pass with -exec echo {}, or - if you are *very* scared - use rm -i {} which ask you each time or rm - v {} so you see what you delete.

Comment: Just confirming this worked for me on Mac OSX mavericks.

Comment: Where can I set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE? Is there some kind of file I can edit?

Comment: when deleting many files, this command may have an issue.. especially when memory on the machine that you are running the command on is low. Andy Baker's answer is much better.

Answer (score 1071):

`find . -name '*.pyc' -type f -delete`

Surely the simplest.

Comment: If your version of `find` supports `-delete`; it is not part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: This ignores .pyo files and `__pycache__` directories. See my answer.

Comment: I used the code from the accepted answer and it worked, but these commands are shorter and simple

Comment: @MattCaldwell Is `rm` not sufficient (drop `-f`)?

Comment: @RuddZwolinski it doesn't feel safer when you *think* you know it by heart, don't, omit the `-name` and delete your entire env!

Comment: `-name '*.py?'` to include `.pyo, .pyc,...`

Comment: MAKE SURE -delete is the last thing in the command. I accidentally put          -delete right after the find. It deleted everything!

Comment: make sure about what you are going to do here, if you are inside the python virtual environment and if you executes this command it will remove the entire .pyc in the virtual environment as well.

Answer (score 96):

Add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
pyclean () {
        find . -type f -name "*.py[co]" -delete
        find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete
}
```

This removes all .pyc and .pyo files, and `__pycache__` directories. It's also very fast.

Usage is simply:

```
$ cd /path/to/directory
$ pyclean
```

Comment: `find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete` will often give a warning about a missing path because apparently the contents will be added to the queue before the folder is deleted. `2>/dev/null` should fix that.

Answer (score 88):

In current version of debian you have `pyclean` script which is in `python-minimal` package.

Usage is simple:

```
pyclean .
```

Comment: It's worth noting that pyclean appears to only delete .pyc files for which there is a corresponding .py file (at least on my system - ubuntu 12.10.)

This means it's not very helpful in situations where a source file has been deleted and you want to clean up the leftover .pyc files.

Comment: @holms `pyclean` (and now [`py3clean`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python3-minimal)) originate in a Debian package, and thus aren’t in RHEL.

Comment: The `pyclean` command is now available as a Python package [installable from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyclean/), which work cross-platform (including RHEL, macOS and Windows). It deletes any `.pyc` file w/o special preference as of today.

Answer (score 53):

If you're using bash >=4.0 (or zsh)

```
rm **/*.pyc
```

Note that `*/*.pyc` selects all `.pyc` files in the immediate first-level subdirectories while `**/*.pyc` recursively scans the whole directory tree. As an example, `foo/bar/qux.pyc` will be deleted by `rm **/*.pyc` but not by `*/*.pyc`.

The globstar shell options must be enabled. To enable `globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and to check its status:

```
shopt globstar
```

Comment: What's the difference in running `rm **/*.pyc` vs `rm */*.pyc`?  (The latter seemed to work for me locally.)

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston `rm */*.pyc` will delete all `.pyc` files in all subdirectories of depth 1. `rm **/*.pyc` will delete all `.pyc` files in all subdirectories of depth 0+

Comment: @AdamStewart Thanks for adding this.  For others stumbling on this thread, the issue I was experiencing was that Apple's bash shipped with OS X doesn't include globstar (so `**` acts as `*` when run instead and running `shopt globstar` throws an error).

Answer (score 35):

For windows users:

```
del /S *.pyc
```

Comment: Putting this in a batch script makes things super easy. Thanks.

Comment: And if you are on Powershell, this can be used with "cmd" -> Run command -> "exit".

Answer (score 30):

I used to use an alias for that:

```
$ which pycclean

pycclean is aliased to `find . -name "*.pyc" | xargs -I {} rm -v "{}"'
```

Comment: In current debian it is pyclean.

Comment: This doesn't deal with whitespace in filenames well. You should use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` instead.

Comment: Why would you want to have python code with spaces in the file/folder names? Is that syntactically legal?

Comment: @CoreDumpError, yes, in fact on Windows Python installs to a directory with spaces ("Program Files").

Comment: The python interpreter may install there by default, but it's hardly a good place to put your *code*. Plus, you certainly wouldn't want the Program Files folder to be part of your package structure, which is why I was wary about syntax.

Answer (score 18):

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

The find recursively looks for *.pyc files.  The xargs takes that list of names and sends it to rm.  The -print0 and the -0 tell the two commands to seperate the filenames with null characters.  This allows it to work correctly on file names containing spaces, and even a file name containing a new line.

The solution with -exec works, but it spins up a new copy of rm for every file.  On a slow system or with a great many files, that'll take too long.

You could also add a couple more args:

```
find . -iname '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty  rm
```

iname adds case insensitivity, like *.PYC .  The no-run-if-empty keeps you from getting an error from rm if you have no such files.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

This is faster than

```
$ find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 15):

Further, people usually want to remove all `*.pyc`, `*.pyo` files and `__pycache__` directories recursively in the current directory.

Command:

```
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but a plain Python solution would be cross-platform and hence preferable. While, personally, I don't care about Windows probably half of the Python population lives on Windows -- and `find`, `grep` and friends don't work there.

Comment: They do if you install the tooling.  I'd recommend every windows CLI user do so to ease cross-compat: https://superuser.com/questions/168202/difference-between-unxutils-and-gnuwin32

Answer (score 11):

### Django Extension

> Note: This answer is very specific to **[Django project](https://www.djangoproject.com/)** that have already been using [Django Extension](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions).

```
python manage.py clean_pyc
```

The implementation can be viewed in [its source code](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/clean_pyc.py).

Answer (score 8):

Just to throw another variant into the mix, you can also use backquotes like this:

```
rm `find . -name *.pyc`
```

Comment: This has the slight drawback of failing if there are too many matches, as there will be too many arguments to pass to `rm`.

Answer (score 7):

full recursive

```
ll **/**/*.pyc
rm **/**/*.pyc
```

Comment: Interesting, how does this compare to Andy and Bill's answers?

Comment: One set of `**` is redundant, and as in `d0k`'s answer, you must have globstar enabled in bash 4+ for this to work as intended. i.e. do `shopt -s globstar` or have that in one of your sourced bash . files.

Comment: Also `ll` is commonly aliased to something like `ls -l`, but isn't really a command or portable. So, to recursively list all `.pyc` files in `.`, you should instead do something like `echo **/*.pyc` with globstar enabled

Answer (score 5):

There is the [pyclean](https://pypi.org/project/pyclean/) package on PyPI and Anaconda, which is easy to use and cross-platform.

```bash
python -m pip install pyclean
```

You then just need to run a simple command to clean all `__pycache__` folders and `*.pyc` files in current dir:

```bash
pyclean .
```

It also has additional options to delete various artifacts from running builds and tests.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want .pyc anymore you can use this single line in a terminal:

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

if you change your mind:

```
unset PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
```

Answer (score 3):

First run:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py[c|o]" -exec rm -f {} +
```

Then add:

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

To ~/.profile

Answer (score 2):

`rm -r` recurses into directories, but only the directories you give to `rm`. It will also delete those directories. One solution is:

```
for i in $( find . -name *.pyc )
do
  rm $i
done
```

`find` will find all *.pyc files recursively in the current directory, and the `for` loop will iterate through the list of files found, removing each one.

Comment: This one works though I have to put it in a .sh file and run that (which is fine by me, I'll be using this command more than once)

Comment: I believe putting it all on one line separated with ';'s should let you run it at the shell. But when I type that in bash, bash waits for the "done" at the end to execute anything...

Comment: That's an awful _antipattern_ (and a very common one too, I wish it could disappear): it breaks with filenames containing spaces or glob characters. And it misses the point of `find` with its `-exec` predicate: `find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} +` (nicer, shorter, safer, robust, more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.pyc"|xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete all the .pyc files from the project folder.

First, you have

```
cd <path/to/the/folder>
```

then find all the .pyc file and delete.

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `find . -name "*.pyc" -type f -delete`.

But use it with precaution. Run first `find . -name "*.pyc" -type f` to see exactly which files you will remove.

In addition, make sure that -delete is the last argument in your command. If you put it before the -name *.pyc argument, it will delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

To delete all the python compiled files in current directory.

```
find . -name "__pycache__"|xargs rm -rf
find . -name "*.pyc"|xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove all `*.pyc` files and `__pycache__` directories recursively in the current directory:

- with python:

```py
import os

os.popen('find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf')
```

- or manually with terminal or cmd:

```sh
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

`py3clean` works for me!

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.9
sudo py3clean -v .
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add a few ignore params on M1:

```
pyclean --verbose . --ignore "Library",".Trash"
```

Answer (score 0):

`DEL /F /S /Q  "Z:\aaa\*.pyc"`

use cmd, or save in bat file, in window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In windows where find wont work. Here is a python function which can be run in ipython or python default interpretor or run as a script. Just putting for easy accessibility for some one.

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import remove

def remove_files(pth, filetype = "*.pyc"):
   pth = Path(pth)
   for file in pth.glob(f"**/{filetype}"):
   remove(file)
```

You can call the function as:

```
target_folder = <path to clean>
remove_files(target_folder)
```