# Automatically deleting pyc files when corresponding py is moved (Mercurial)

Tags: python, mercurial

(I foresaw this problem might happen 3 months ago, and was told to be diligent to avoid it. Yesterday, I was bitten by it, hard, and now that it has cost me real money, I am keen to fix it.)

If I move one of my Python source files into another directory, I need to remember to tell Mercurial that it moved (`hg move`).

When I deploy the new software to my server with Mercurial, it carefully deletes the old Python file and creates it in the new directory.

However, Mercurial is unaware of the pyc file in the same directory, and leaves it behind. The old pyc is used preferentially over new python file by other modules in the same directory.

What ensues is NOT hilarity.

How can I persuade Mercurial to automatically delete my old pyc file when I move the python file? Is there another better practice? Trying to remember to delete the pyc file from all the Mercurial repositories isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have actually done:

1) I am considering Nicholas Knight's suggestion about using a proper deployment strategy. I have been reading about [Buildout](http://buildout.org) and [Collective.hostout](http://plone.org/products/collective.hostout) to learn more. I need to decide whether such heavy-weight strategies are worthwhile for my project's relatively simple requirements.

2) I have adopted Ry4an's update hook concept, in the short-term, until I decide.

3) I ignored Ry4an's warning about overkill, and wrote a Python script to only delete stray .pyc files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" Searches subdirectories of the current directory looking for .pyc files which
    do not have matching .py files, and deletes them.

    This is useful as a hook for version control when Python files are moved.
    It is dangerous for projects that deliberately include Python 
    binaries without source.
"""
import os
import os.path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    pyc_files = filter(lambda filename: filename.endswith(".pyc"), files)
    py_files = set(filter(lambda filename: filename.endswith(".py"), files))
    excess_pyc_files = filter(lambda pyc_filename: pyc_filename[:-1] not in py_files, pyc_files)
    for excess_pyc_file in excess_pyc_files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root, excess_pyc_file)
        print "Removing old PYC file:", full_path
        os.remove(full_path)
```

My update hooks now call this rather than the "find" commands suggested by others.

Comment: That'll work.  You could have the udpate hook invoke a subroutine your .py file directly if you'd like.  You just name it hook and provide the path to the .py file.  That'll save you spinning up a whole 'nother python VM.

Comment: Thanks, Ry4an. Wish I could give you more rep for that suggestion.

Comment: For posterity, this `find` command plus sh loop is similar: `find . -path './virtualenv/*' -prune -or -name '*.pyc' -print | while read f; do [[ ! -f "${f%?}" ]] && echo "$f" && rm "$f"; done`

Answer (score 16):

1. Do not store .pyc files in the repository.
2. Automatize .pyc delete with: find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
3. While develop use -B argument in Python.

Comment: Also, precompile all the .pyc files on the release. You deploy by tagging the repo, and pushing to production, etc. Compiling .pyc files fits in there. For other languages compiling binaries is the most natural thing under the sun.

Comment: 1) I am not storing .pyc files in the repository.

2) I like the command. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785519/remove-all-pyc-files-from-a-project for more. I guess I am looking at help "automatizing".

3) I looked this up. Don't store byte code for imported modules? Why not?

Comment: Why does this answer have 16 upvotes when it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: about 2., why not `rm *.pyc`? To delete pyc recursively if sub-folders exists?

Answer (score 9):

How about using an [update hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) on the server side?  Put this in the repository's `.hg` directory's `hgrc` file:

```
[hooks]
update = find . -name '*.pyc' | xargs rm
```

That will delete all .pyc files whenever you update on the server.  If you're worried about the cost of rebuilding all the .pyc files you could always get just a little more clever in the hook and delete only the .pyc's for which there is no .py, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks. This was the info I needed. I went ahead and overkilled. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

You need:

1) A real deployment infrastructure, even if it's just a shell script, which does everything. Cloning/checking out an updated copy from source control is not a deployment strategy.

2) Any deployment system should completely clean the directory structure. My usual preference is that each deployment happens to a new directory named with a date+timestamp, and a symlink (with a name like "current") is updated to point to the new directory. This gives you breadcrumbs on each server should something go wrong.

3) To fix whatever is running the Python code. New .py source files should always take precedence over cached .pyc files. If that is not the behavior you are seeing, it is a bug, and you need to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: Python is easy, copy out the .py files (and whatever else you need) and ignore the .pyc files (well, you get the idea).

Comment: To point 3, the reason it's not happening is because the .py doesn't exist.  Without the .py present there's no time to compare and python doesn't just ignore the pyc that has no .py.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on 1). With the obvious exception of the .pyc files discussed here, the "hg pull -u" strategy is working well for me.

I should mention that I have exactly one target machine (although I have several repositories for testing). My staging machine and production machine are the same, but using different accounts and config files so they don't stomp on each other. Performance,  availability and scaling are not important on this project.

Comment: Performance, availability, and scaling are, to one degree or another, default requirements for any meaningful project, raising questions about what it is you're doing. Nevertheless, raw experience teaches that you shouldn't assume you can predict what stray files may find their way into a deployed tree. In doing so, you engage in a classic engineering error of trying to correct for every possible individual problem, instead of trying to make it impossible for anything other than the "right thing" to occur in the first place. Down the former path lies madness.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Let me address the first sentence first. Yes, I have performance requirements, but I am over-achieving them, while consuming 3% of CPU and 25% of RAM on a low-end virtual server, so I don't need to optimise. My server is only required to be available for a few hours each day, so there is plenty of time to deploy new versions without impacting the business. It has already scaled to full size, and is bespoke for exactly one customer, so scaling is not an issue. (An unusual project, I agree. Great to work on!)

Comment: I want to make sure I have understood your key point: Pulling the latest files from Mercurial is not a (sufficient) deployment strategy, because it risks having ongoing problems of the exact type I have had: stray files leak into the directory tree affecting the production server in unpredicted ways. Is that right? Thanks again; food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a unix one-liner that will delete .pyc files each time you run `hg update`.

Add this to your hgrc file:

```
[hooks]
preupdate.cleanpyc = hg status --no-status --removed --deleted --include "**.py" --rev .:$HG_PARENT1 --print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' rm -f '{}c'
```

This runs just prior to update, and gets all .py files which will be removed or deleted when the update is performed, and then deletes corresponding .pyc files.

Here's a quick breakdown of how it works:

```
hg status --no-status --removed --deleted --include "**.py" --rev .:$HG_PARENT1
```

This gets all files removed (e.g. `hg forget`) or deleted (`hg rm`, `hg mv`, etc) between the current revision `.` and the destination (`$HG_PARENT`). You could add `--subrepos` to get all changes in sub-repositories as well if you use that feature.

```
xargs -0 -I '{}' rm -f '{}c'
```

This simply adds a 'c' to the end of each file name returned from `hg status` and tries to delete it.  The `-f` flag for `rm` ensures that it doesn't error if the .pyc file does not exist.

Note that mercurial automatically deletes empty directories after an update, but orphaned .pyc files often cause directories to be left around.  Since this runs before update, it ensure that empty directories are properly deleted.

Comment: Can you explain how it works? It seems to include only (removed/deleted) .pyc files that were previously stored in Mercurial, but no .pyc files are stored in Mercurial.

Comment: You're right, corrected a typo.  It should be clear now, but I've also added a more thorough explanation

Answer (score 1):

I use the `.hgignore` file to skip versionning of all my .pyc and .py~ (editor's temp files). For example, this is my version :

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

.directory
*.pyc
*~
*.o
*.tgz
*.tbz2
*.gz
*.bz2
```

Also adding a hook on update to remove them is also a interesting trick if you want to not only ignore noise but remove it from your local workspace area.

Comment: Thanks, edomaur, but I already have an .hgignore file (actually two - one cross-project and another project-specific.)

I am not versioning .pyc files. That isn't the root problem.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure what you were aiming for, but I think I've understand now.

Answer (score 0):

i use this script to delete the .pyc files in the current folder, this script could be used alone or include it in the exit function to delete the .pyc files when u exit.

```
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and '.pyc' in str(f)]
for f in files : os.unlink(os.getcwd()+'/'+f)
```