# Why was an old .pyc file breaking Django?

Tags: python, django

I pulled the latest code using git today and I got the following error:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name Like
```

This might have something to do with circular imports. I examined the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/Desktop/python/mystuff/Project/Project/urls.py" in <module>
  7. admin.autodiscover()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
```

The only code in there it looked that could be causing the problem was `urls.py`. That had the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

So around this time I notice that the admin.py file that we previously had written was deleted in the latest merge but that the admin.pyc still existed. Deleting the .pyc file proceeded to fix the circular import error and now things seem to work fine.

My question is: what exactly was happening here? Git is configured to ignore all pyc files so after the merge the .pyc stuck around even though the .py was removed. But shouldn't python be smart enough not to try to call any compiled code in the .pyc if the .py itself was deleted?

Comment: It doesn't know it was deleted, and it actually always tries to use `pyc` if there's no `py` or if `py` is older.

Comment: Add this to your `root_directory/.gitignore` file: `*.pyc`. It will tell git to ignore python bytecodes. It's not a good idea to have `pyc` to be part of the repo, since each local feature would edit them, and it could lead to runtime errors if you push them to others that don't have your new modules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, in fact, Python will use the `.pyc` file preferably and only access the `.py` file if it a) exists and b) is newer than the `.pyc` file.

This allows you to distribute a Python app in compiled form without the source code (although it's not much of a code "obfuscation" technique).

Comment: This feature also allows Linux distributions to have the `.py` files of installed packages in a single place and put the `.pyc` files in each Python version's `lib` directory (which is a perhaps more useful application).

Answer (score 9):

Nope, Python is (intentionally, see below) dumb about this! You can run

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

from your project directory to get rid of old `.pyc` files.

If you're using git, you can [set up a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810193/999608) to do this automatically on checkout. Here's a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528283/automatically-deleting-pyc-files-when-corresponding-py-is-moved-mercurial) for Mercurial.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "dumb".  It was an intentional design decision to support this, and it has several use cases.  It's a feature.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think the "dumb" part is it doesn't provide a nice way to clean them up when they are broken.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you can do to prevent this is to start django with

```
python -B manage.py runserver
```

or to automate deletion of pyc, probably with clean_pyc from django-extensions

```
./manage.py clean_pyc
```