# Django admin - delete_selected problem

Tags: django, django-admin

In admin.py file i paste:

```
admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

And get an error:

> KeyError at /
>
> 'delete_selected'
>
> Django Version:   1.3 Exception Type:     KeyError Exception Value:
>
> 'delete_selected'
>
> Exception Location:
>     c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py
>   in disable_action, line 127

Any idea why it occurs? In my previous websites I haven't that error and it is strange for me.

Comment: are you doing it twice, or is the code being imported twice? the admin code just does this: del self._actions[name]   so if the second time around it already deleted it, you'd receive a key error

Answer (score 2):

delete the `admin.pyc` file in your apps directory

Comment: I deleted all the .pyc files and it worked http://stackoverflow.com/a/785534/1248811

Answer (score 2):

This got rid of the issue for me. Just a quick test for 'delete_selected' before disabling the action.

```
if 'delete_selected' in admin.site.actions:
    admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

Cheers