# Python Interpreter Not Reading Indents Properly After Turning on VIM Auto-Indenting

Tags: python, interpreter

I'm not entirely sure what has happened.

I was debugging a script that worked "fine" (except for said intermittent bugs) and all of a sudden the module cannot be imported anymore. I undid all changes and still the problem exists.
Well, problemS. Plural.

Once I got an "unexpected indent" error, even though all the lines were perfectly indented. I fixed that one by deleting the line and retyping it.

Now in the following code, I get one of two errors:

```
class Lottery:
    def __init__(self, session):
          self.prizes = PrizeList()
          self.session = session
          self.players = self.session.listof.players.split(',')
          self.pickWinner()
```

Most of the time, it gives me an error saying "session" is not defined. This is true. I'm just importing the module. It gets defined when the script calling it runs it. I experimented with just removing that line altogether, and then it told me that "self" was not defined.

All of that is the original code that was working 20 minutes ago. the bugs I was fixing are on a different part of this module altogether, and it was certainly importing without problems. Please help!

Traceback:

```
  File "minecraft/mcAdmin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lottery.lottery import *
  File "/home/tomthorogood/minecraft/lottery/lottery.py", line 36, in <module>
    class Lottery:
  File "/home/tomthorogood/minecraft/lottery/lottery.py", line 39, in Lottery
    self.session = session
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

EDIT: SOLVED. Okay, somehow while editing, I *did* accidentally switch between tabs and spacing, which lead to the problem. I deleted and re-wrote that block of code exactly as pasted above and now it's working. There was a ghost indent problem.

DOUBLE EDIT: the core problem was that I only recently turned on auto-indenting in Vim. The configuration I am using is not using tabs as auto-indents, but I was using tabs in the past.

Comment: Can you provide us with a [Short, Self-Contained Correct Example](http://videobb.com/video/inDeNEW9wbTY) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All that's happening is "from lottery.lottery import *".

Comment: Any chance you are mixing TAB characters and space characters in your source file?

Comment: Have you tried removing your .pyc files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785519/remove-all-pyc-files-from-a-project Otherwise it may be due to caching so you might need to clear cache manually or wait for timeout.

Comment: don't you have a version control system?

Comment: @funkotron - Just tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: @yi_h it's a simple script to give prizes in Minecraft I developed one Saturday morning. There was no reason to use a version control system that I could see.

Comment: Can you post the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem, or at least post the error message you get.  A couple thoughts: 'Class' should be 'class' with a lowercase 'c'.  Your unexpected indent error was probably caused by mixing tabs and spaces.  Text editors will sometimes add spaces when you press tab, and sometimes add a tab character.  You should consistently use either tabs or spaces for indenting.  The usual Python standard is four space indents.

Comment: @Tom: now you see the reason.

Comment: @Ned - Good thought. My VIM does autoindenting. To be safe, I just joined all the lines onto one line and manually re-defined them, but to no avail.

Comment: This a clean **NameError**. fix it, rename session to _session

Comment: @peter - The problem is reproduced when importing the module. No part of the program is even run because of this. Int he program C is lowercase, that was a mistake in copy-pasting on here (I didn't copy-paste that line, so typed it in manually)

Comment: obviously, you should be using emacs, as God intended us to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an indentation problem.

The `self.session = session` line, and everything below, isn't inside your `__init__` method, it's just inside the `class` body.

`session` isn't defined in the class body, only inside `__init__`, as you mention in your question, so you get the error.

IF you remove that line, the first thing that gets looked up is the `self` in `self.players = self.session.listof.players.split(',')`, so you get the `self` is not defined error.

Comment: And "d'oh!" about the removing that line and wondering why 'self' wasn't defined. I'm still confused about self.session=session, though.

Comment: thank you. I deleted and re-wrote that block of code and it does work now. I think you and Peter were both correct about the indentation. It LOOKED indented, but it must have been a faulty space/tab mixup, so the interpreter didn't read it as such.

Comment: I also changed the title of the post so it could be useful to someone else, now that I know what the problem was.

Comment: I'm setting that up as we speak! I never had the need before, even with Python. I have changed my .vimrc around a bit and added some auto folding, etc., so that could be the core issue.

Comment: Next time try to locate the code giving an error by refactoring you code first, in any language you use.

Comment: Yup. That's totally the issue. I hadn't edited this script since adding the autoindent feature. Everything from before is tabbed, but everything now is autoindented, which is not technically a tab.