# When are .pyc files refreshed?

Tags: python, python-internals, pyc

I understand that ".pyc" files are compiled versions of the plain-text ".py" files, created at runtime to make programs run faster. However I have observed a few things:

1. Upon modification of "py" files, program behavior changes. This indicates that the "py" files are compiled or at least go though some sort of hashing process or compare time stamps in order to tell whether or not they should be re-compiled.
2. Upon deleting all ".pyc" files (`rm *.pyc`) sometimes program behavior will change. Which would indicate that they are not being compiled on update of ".py"s.

Questions:

- How do they decide when to be compiled?
- Is there a way to ensure that they have stricter checking during development?

Comment: Beware of deleting .pyc files with `rm *.pyc`.  This will not delete .pyc files in nested folders.  Use `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` instead

Comment: Perhaps one note on your question: A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ file than when it is read from a ‘.py’ file; the only thing that's faster about ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ files is the speed with which they are loaded. [link](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html)

Comment: @maggie what's the difference between loading and execution time?

Comment: @Dani loading is the time it takes to read and then compile the program. Execution time is when the program is actually being run which happens after loading. If you want to be technical, the time types are load time, compile time, link time, and execution time. Making a .pyc eliminates the compile time part.

Comment: @EricKlien thanks man

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `.pyc` files are created (and possibly overwritten) only when that python file is imported by some other script. If the import is called, Python checks to see if the `.pyc` file's internal timestamp is not older than the corresponding `.py` file.  If it is, it loads the `.pyc`; if it isn't or if the `.pyc` does not yet exist, Python compiles the `.py` file into a `.pyc` and loads it.

What do you mean by "stricter checking"?

Comment: I am able to fix problems with `rm *.pyc`. I know that if I force all the files to be recreated then some issues are fixed, indicating that the files are not being re-compiled by themselves. I suppose that if they do use the timestamps then there is no way to make this behavior stricter, but the problem still persists.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The timestamps don't need to match (and they usually don't). The `.pyc`'s timestamp must be *older* than the corresponding `.py`'s timestamp to trigger a recompilation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah, of course that makes sense. Good to know. And OP, there are also other kinds of files that can be imported by Python. A `.so`, for example, is a compiled C extension that can be called by Python as if it were a `.pyc` file. Beyond that I'd need more details about your problem to offer anything else.

Comment: @Aaron, Are you possibly changing the .py files, and in the process making them older (e.g. by copying them in from another dir, using an operation which preserves 'modification time')?

Comment: @greggo, I'm using git and updating from a repository, so yes in a way I am. That could do it. Thanks.

Comment: *Good to know.* How about correcting your answer then?

Comment: I don't think @TimPietzcker's comment is correct. Here's the relevant source for Python 3.6: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4134f154ae2f621f25c5d698cc0f1748035a1b88/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L470. The last-modified timestamp on the `.py` file has to _exactly_ match the timestamp that's embedded in the header of the `.pyc` file. (The timestamp of the `.pyc` file itself is irrelevant, and more recent versions of Python don't use timestamps at all in the `.pyc` header.)

Answer (score 35):

.pyc files generated whenever the corresponding code elements are imported, and updated if the corresponding code files have been updated.  If the .pyc files are deleted, they will be automatically regenerated.  However, they are **not** automatically deleted when the corresponding code files are deleted.

This can cause some really fun bugs during file-level refactors.

First of all, you can end up pushing code that only works on your machine and on no one else's.  If you have dangling references to files you deleted, these will still work locally if you don't manually delete the relevant .pyc files because .pyc files can be used in imports.  This is compounded with the fact that a properly configured version control system will only push .py files to the central repository, not .pyc files, meaning that your code can pass the "import test" (does everything import okay) just fine and not work on anyone else's computer.

Second, you can have some pretty terrible bugs if you turn packages into modules.  When you convert a package (a folder with an `__init__.py` file) into a module (a .py file), the .pyc files that once represented that package remain.  In particular, the `__init__.pyc` remains.  So, if you have the package foo with some code that doesn't matter, then later delete that package and create a file foo.py with some function `def bar(): pass` and run:

```
from foo import bar
```

you get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name bar
```

because python is still using the old .pyc files from the foo package, none of which define bar.  This can be especially problematic on a web server, where totally functioning code can break because of .pyc files.

As a result of both of these reasons (and possibly others), your deployment code and testing code should delete .pyc files, such as with the following line of bash:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

Also, as of python 2.6, you can run python with the `-B` flag to not use .pyc files.  See [How to avoid .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files) for more details.

See also: [How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785519/how-do-i-remove-all-pyc-files-from-a-project)

Comment: "When you convert a module (a folder with an `__init__.py` file)...".  That would be a package, not a module.

Comment: *In particular, the `__init__.pyc` remains.* – How come? As a package is a directory deleting a package means deleting directory thus there are no files left…

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Properly managed source control involves not checking your pyc files into source.  So while you may delete the folder, including pyc files, in your local copy, it will not be deleted for someone else who does a git pull.  This can crash your server if your deployment involves a git pull as well.

Comment: There are many reasons to not trust your dev environment to be representative of where your code will be deployed. This `.pyc` issue is one reason, also: hidden dependencies on OS and utility patch levels, `.so` files, config files, other Python libs (if you're not running in a virtual env), obscure env vars ... the list goes on. To be thorough and find all such issues, you need to make a clean copy of your code in a git repo or publish as a package to a PyPi style server, and do a full clone or setup on a fresh VM. Some of those potential problems make this `.pyc` issue pale in comparison.