# Python pickle instance has no attribute

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to crawl a website. In this website i store the crawled persons in person_set, and the queue for crawling next persons in parse_queue. At the starting of the each person crawl, i need to write these two data structures into a file in case crawling interrupts due to exceptions or bad connection so i can continue later.

I have three python files. A main file, a spider, and a person model. Main instantiates spider, spider starts parsing and calls write and read when necessary. person file has the class Person which is the model for storing person data.

I'm having problems with reading the data i wrote. I checked many questions about this error and it seems like an import problem. But even though i imported Person class into main and spiders it's still giving me error. It seems like emergency_read method is not affected by my top level import.

main.py

```
from spiders import Spider
from person import Person
import pickle

def main():
    ....
    spider = Spider("seed_input")
    spider.parse(client)
```

spiders.py

```
import pickle
from person import Person

class Spider:

    def __init__(self, filename):
            self.person_set = Set()

            self.file_to_seed(filename)
            for seed_url in self.seed_list:
                    self.seed_to_parse_queue(seed_url)

    def parse(self, client):
        if os.path.exists('tmp.person_set'):
                print "Program wasnt ended properly, continuing from where it left"
                self.emergency_read()

        ... starts parsing

    def emergency_write(self):

        if os.path.exists('tmp.person_set'):
            self.delete_emergency_files()

        with open('tmp.person_set', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.person_set, f)

        with open('tmp.parse_queue', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.parse_queue, f)

    def emergency_read(self):
        with open('tmp.person_set', 'rb') as f:
            self.person_set = pickle.load(f)

        with open('tmp.parse_queue', 'rb') as f:
            self.parse_queue = pickle.load(f)
```

person.py

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.friend_set = Set()
            self.profile_url = ""
            self.id = 0
            self.color = "Grey"
            self.parent = None
            self.depth = 0

    def add_friend(self, friend):
            self.friend_set.add(friend)

    def __repr__(self):
            return "Person(%s, %s)" % (self.profile_url, self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, Person):
                return ((self.profile_url == other.profile_url) and (self.name == other.name))
            else:
                return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
            return (not self.__eq__(other))

    def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.__repr__())
```

Stacktrace

```
python main.py 
Program wasnt ended properly, continuing from where it left
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 34, in main
spider.parse(client)
File "/home/ynscn/py-workspace/lll/spiders.py", line 39, in parse
self.emergency_read()
File "/home/ynscn/py-workspace/lll/spiders.py", line 262, in emergency_read
self.person_set = pickle.load(f)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1198, in load_setitem
dict[key] = value
File "/home/ynscn/py-workspace/lll/person.py", line 30, in __hash__
return hash(self.__repr__())
File "/home/ynscn/py-workspace/lll/person.py", line 18, in __repr__
return "Person(%s, %s)" % (self.profile_url, self.name)
AttributeError: Person instance has no attribute 'profile_url'
```

Comment: Can you share the module file structure tree?

Comment: Can you try nuking all your .pyc files and re-running the script? Particularly person.pyc. Maybe there is a possibility that an older version of the module (pyc) file is being imported instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839555/when-are-pyc-files-refreshed

Comment: I tried nuking .pyc files, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle loads the components of a class instance in a non-deterministic order. This error is happening during the load but before it has deserialized the `Person.profile_url` attribute. Notice that it fails during `load_setitem`, which means it is probably trying to load the `friend_set` attribute, which is a set.

Your custom `__repr__()` relies on a class attribute, and then your custom `__hash__()` (which is needed by `pickle`) relies on `__repr__()`.

My recommendation is to use Python's default `__hash__` method. Would that work?

Comment: Removing hash method works but I need that hash method to store person instances in a set by looking their profile_url's. How can i do that?

Comment: Another idea is to serialize using JSON instead of pickle as long as Person contains only built-in types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable

Comment: @YnScN, were you able to find a solution that achieved that goal while avoiding this error?

Comment: @JoshK your comment sent me down to the memory lane :) I couldn't find the exact codes to show you the solution, but I believe I followed the JSON approach for serialization

Answer (score 0):

Your code might serialize ***as is*** if you use `dill` instead of `pickle`.  `dill` can pickle class objects, instances, methods, and attributes… and most everything in python. `dill` can also store dynamically modified state for classes and class instances. I agree that it seems to be a pickle `load` error, as @nofinator points out.  However, `dill` might let to get around it.

Probably even better might be that if you want to force an order for load and unload, you could try adding `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods.

Comment: Dill also returns the same error, i guess i'll have to implement my own storing logic with JSON.

Comment: Well it was worth the try, I guess…  but I do think `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` **would** work for you.