# Django ImportError: cannot import name get_permission_codename

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am doing the tango with django tutorial. I am up to chapter 5 on working with models and I am setting up the admin website. I get this strange error:

> ImportError: cannot import name get_permission_codename

This seems to go away when I remove the

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

from my project/urls.py. But I am concerned that I will need this down the road.

Here is the Traceback I get when I run the development server:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
>
> Django Version: 1.5.4 Python Version: 2.7.3 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.admin',  'rango') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in resolve
>     319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in url_patterns
>     347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
>   in urlconf_module
>     342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in
>   import_module
>     35.     **import**(name) File "/home/gpanterov/MyProjects/django/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/urls.py"
>   in 
>     6. admin.autodiscover() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/**init**.py"
>   in autodiscover
>     29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in
>   import_module
>     35.     **import**(name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/admin.py"
>   in 
>     5. from django.contrib.admin.checks import InlineModelAdminChecks File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py"
>   in 
>     6. from django.contrib.admin.utils import get_fields_from_path, NotRelationField, flatten File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py"
>   in 
>     6. from django.contrib.auth import get_permission_codename
>
> Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/ Exception Value: cannot import
>   name get_permission_codename

When I remove the admin.autodiscover() line, the development server runs and I am able to get to the admin panel, but when I log in with the superuser password I created earlier, I get the message "You don't have permission to edit anything." and I don't see any of the categories I created.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when downgrading django from latest version (1.8) to an old version (1.4) for testing.

The problem here is that git doesn't delete `.pyc` files when switching branches (because they are `.gitignore`'ed) and python only regenerates them when the corresponding `.py` file is *newer* than the `.pyc` file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839555/when-are-pyc-files-refreshed) for details).

The solution is to delete all `*.pyc` files in `django/contrib/admin` and `django/contrib/contenttypes` directories.

Answer (score 0):

cannot import name get_permission_codename

Make sure u have not install all the version of django in your system.
if there then remove all and install fresh django