# manage.py runserver importerror

Tags: python, django

after running 
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

I get this error message

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x7fefc10b9190>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import get_permission_codename
ImportError: cannot import name get_permission_codename
```

I've checked out /django/contrib/auth/management/**init**.py
and the get_permission_codename function exists so I can't see why it's not getting imported.

Comment: did you checked if in setting.py file, django.admin.contrib app is not commented

Comment: I've uncommented the line but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772522/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-get-permission-codename)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have Django 1.6 or later installed, because that's when `get_permission_codename` was added.

The problem might be with old `pyc` files. You could get rid of these by uninstalling Django completely then reinstalling.

Comment: ok upgraded django but it's thrown another error. might try asking on chat tomorrow.