# Updated code not executing on server

Tags: python, django

I've modified a .py file on a production server and the changes are not being applied. At first I thought this was because the associated .pyc file was not being updated. So I deleted the `.pyc` file and tested hoping the `.py` file would compile into a new `.pyc` file. The applications behavior did not update and a new `.pyc` file was not created. [This was done based off a previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375708/)

How is it that the script is executing without generating a new `.pyc` file? Here are the two files in question:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  47872 Jul 13 04:39 admin_email.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    48212 Feb 10 03:12 admin_email.pyc
```

`admin_email.pyc` has been deleted. Only `admin_email.py` remains on there server.

Here is the code that is executing the script that has been changed:

```
from xxx.admin_email import send_email_admins
...
g = lambda x, y, z: send_email_admins(x, y, z)
...
threading.Thread(target=g, args=(order_id, request.user.email, form.cleaned_data)).start()
```

The application is being served with `gunicorn` + `nginx`.

Any ideas on what the issue is? Why is a new `.pyc` file being created? More importantly why is the applications behavior not being updated?

Comment: How is the application being served? I know with passenger wsgi, you need to refesh/update the server for changes to be applied.

Comment: With `gunicorn` + `nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you're suing wsgi or fcgi - most probably on apache or nginx

With wsgi - normally apache will cache your django for you.

So, you need to tell apache/nginx/server-provider that your django code has changed. The way you do this is by changing the "last edited" meta information of your `.wsgi` file. So, you simple do `touch /path/to/django.wsgi` and it will normally work.

If you use fcgi, the same thing applies.

Comment: OK I changed the last edit of `/.../wsgi.py` by _touching_ it. A new `admin_email.pyc` still has not been created.

Comment: Well, has the admin_email.py code been used in anyway after the wsgi.py was edited ?Is it being imported at all ? A good way of testing this would be to do something like `a = open("tempfile.txt", "w"); a.close()` and checking if the tempfile was created. If it is not created means that the file isnt really being imported at all ... and hence no .pyc - This could be because there's an error in some module before it is getting imported?

Comment: Yes it is being imported. In the above code snippet: `from xxx.admin_email import send_email_admins`

Comment: If you've changed lots of files - it's easier to do `sudo service apache2 reload` (if you've using apache2) - ah, but i see in an above comment you're using gunicorn + nginx - so it'll be a different incantation!

Comment: Yes, if someone could please advise on how to successfully reload or restart a server running  gunicorn + nginx it would be awesome. I did not create this application and there was no documentation created so Im not too sure how to restart or reload the server. Since this is a production server Im worried I will not be able to restart if I do something incorrectly.