# Remove particular files in deep directory by rm command

Tags: rm

I want to remove all png images in particular directory.

I there are following directories and images, how can I remove all png files at once?

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── 3
│   │   └── 3.png
│   └── 2.png
└── 1.png
```

I tried following command.

```
rm -rf *.png       #only 1.png was deleted.
rm -rf **/*.png    #only 2.png was deleted.
rm -rf **/**/*.png #only 3.png was deleted.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `globstar` option (introduced in Bash 4) for the recursive globbing to work

From the [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

> `globstar`
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

So this should work

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -f **/*.png
```

Or alternatively with `find` and the `delete` action

```
find . -name '*.png' -delete
```

---

#### Note on the "-r" switch of `rm`:

`-r` switch "remove directories and their contents recursively" (Source: [man rm](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm)). By default, `rm` can't remove directories. The switch *doesn't* change how filename expansion or globbing works.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -name \*.png | xargs rm`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know 'xargs'. It seems handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This post has a very similar question: [How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785519/how-do-i-remove-all-pyc-files-from-a-project)

Comment: You probably do not want `-r` since that only applies to directories, and you only want to operate on files with this particular exercise.