# After creating a new django application, while running the server it's showing the urls for previous project

Tags: python, django

I am using ATOM ide while I am running new project server it is opening the previous project urls.

I have tried restarting the editor and system also but still not working. Can anyone please advise. This is the new project running.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJxkM.png)

```
 PS C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Django_Projects\simplesocial> python manage.py  
 runserver
 Performing system checks...

 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
 August 06, 2018 - 21:23:25
 Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'simplesocial.settings'
 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK
```

Comment: Please add some code and anything else those can help others to find out your problem.

Comment: I have added the image of previous project and also the code of  current project runserver. please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

inside via your picture, you include only 2 url paths

```html
1. ^admin/
2. employee/
```

That means you have to add either after your (http://127.0.0.1:8000/ <===right here)
or add a path inside your urls.py ===> urlpatterns and this is my list of url path

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view


urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('courses/', include('courses.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('about/<int:id>/', about_view, name='product-detail'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and i'm pretty sure that your urls.py is located at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Django_Projects\simplesocial\urls.py
or if you have add a extra path
hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy your new project from your old project? If so, you may have `.pyc` files left over from the old project.

Try deleting your `.pyc` files (don't worry, Python will regenerate new ones from your `.py` files). Change to your projects root directory, delete all your `.pyc` files, and restart the devserver.

This is the command on Windows:

```
del /S *.pyc
```

This is the command on Mac/Linux:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

(See [How do I remove all .pyc files from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785519/how-do-i-remove-all-pyc-files-from-a-project/785534))

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working by making this change to my older project

Previous **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include 
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'employee/',include('portal.urls'))
 ]
```

After adding  **^** this before **employee**

```
  from django.conf.urls import url,include
  from django.contrib import admin

   urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^employee/',include('portal.urls'))
     ]
```

**The dev server start running urls for current project instead of the previous.This change is done in the older project for which I am receiving the urls.**

Thanks to all for suggestion.