# Stop python from generating pyc files

Tags: python, pyc

When I change my Python code, I often need to delete the associated `pyc` file, or Python will not regenerate it and will run the old code. Is there a way to tell Python not to generated `pyc` files?

Comment: Python should automatically make new `.pyc` files whenever the source `.py` files have changed. Why do you think that is not happening?

Comment: Also, I think this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files

Answer (score 5):

Edit the `.bashrc` file and add the following lines to the very end of the file:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=True
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
```

Restart your terminal or do the following:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

When you import a file, Python will first look at the corresponding `.py` file, and if it's newer than the `.pyc` file, it'll be recompiled.

I'd advise you to check that your system (and its clock) is acting sanely, so the `.py` files you modify get a new modified timestamp.

See the docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files