# Benefits of avoiding .pyc files?

Tags: python

Are there any benefits, performance or otherwise for [avoiding `.pyc` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files), except for the convenience of not having a bunch of these files in the source folder?

Comment: No. If it was better not to have `.pyc`s then Python wouldn't include them =)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there really is. `.pyc` files are cached bytecode files, and you save startup time as Python does not have to recompile your python files every time you start the interpreter.

At most, switching off bytecode compilation lets you measure how much time the interpreter spends on this step. If you want to compare how much time is saved, remove all the `.pyc` files in your project, and time Python by using the -B switch to the interpreter:

```
$ time python -B yourproject
```

then run again without the -B switch:

```
$ time python yourproject
```

It could be that the user under which you want to run your program does not have write access to the source code directories; for example a web server where you do not want remote users to have any chance of altering your source code through a vulnerability. In such cases I'd use the included [`compileall` module](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html) to bytecompile everything using a priviledged user rather than forgo writing `.pyc` files.

Comment: @dkson - actually he didn't, even though I think it's a partial answer

Comment: @dkson: No, I didn't, but I worded it poorly.

Comment: @dkson: No worries, I appreciate feedback and I improve my answers accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can think of: during development, if you remove or rename a `.py` file, the `.pyc` file will stay around in your local copy with the old name and the old bytecode. Since you don't normally commit `.pyc` files to version control, this can lead to stray `ImportError`s that don't happen on your machine, but do on others.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that .pyc files could encourage people to think they need not maintain/ship the original source.  pyc files might not be portable between operating systems and versions of Python.  When moving Python modules it is safer to leave the pyc files behind and just copy or ship the source and let the host python generate new pyc files.
By the way, from Python 3.2 the .pyc files no longer go into the source folder, but in `__pycache__` (in the source folder).

Comment: `.pyc` files are indeed not portable between Python versions and you should never ship code with these unless you package for a specific python version.