# How can I disable generation of pyc and pyo files?

Tags: python, autotools, automake

Autotools insists on generating pyo and pyc files when building my project (not when running it) no matter what I do.  The problem is that my Python configuration is somewhat strange, and I don't want the Python compiler to run during installation.  Is there any way to disable generating these files?

For reference, here are the things I've tried:

- Setting py_compile=echo so that automake won't compile Python scripts
- Manually defining install-pythonPYTHON in Makefile.am
- Setting PYTHONFLAGS=-B
- Setting PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE in Makefile.am, configure.ac, etc.
- Creating a new automake variable "python2dir" and installing the script using dist_python2_DATA = Script.py

Basically, if a file ends with the .py extension, Automake WILL create pyc and pyo files, no matter what you do.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try again with your last attempt.

```
dist_python_DATA = foo.py
```

will treat `foo.py` as any regular file, distribute it, and install it in `$(pythondir)`.  `_DATA` does not trigger any kind of compilation.

Answer (score 2):

See the -B option in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options).

Comment: I need a way to tell automake to use that option when installing Python scripts to site-packages.

Comment: Try setting the **PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE** enviroment variable, which is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

Comment: I tried putting this in configure.ac, Makefile.am, etc.  Didn't work, probably b/c automake has its own environment variables.  This is really an automake/autools problem rather than a Python problem.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @MattFichman: As I understand your problem, autotools generate byte code files *when building your project*.  They will probably be using the `compileall` module, so the command line option and environment variable given in this answer are useless to you – they prevent the automatic creation of pyc/pyo files upon *module import*.  You might want to clarify your question.

Comment: The automake documentation says "any files listed in noinst_PYTHON will not be compiled" [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Python), so maybe you could put *.py in it.

Comment: @martineau: Doing this would also mean that no Python file at all is installed when doing `make install`, which seems hardly useful.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: It only says they won't be _compiled_.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html): The special prefix `noinst_` indicates that the objects in question should be built but not installed at all.