# Is it possible and feasible to compile the entire Python standard library to byte code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyc

Is there an easy way to pre-"compile" the entire Python standard library to byte code? If so, would this also guarantee that Python never re-"compiles" a file if a corresponding `.pyc` file already exists (as long as the standard library is not updated or modified)?

Background: On an application server, Python sometimes spontaneously goes into a broken state that manifests itself like this:

```
C:\> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 552, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 478, in aliasmbcs
    enc = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getdefaultlocale'
```

and that can be resolved by re-installing Python. Someone else told me that he has seen corrupted (0-byte) `.pyc` files and that deleting those solved the problem. However, I cannot reproduce the issue by deliberately creating 0-byte `.pyc` files.

I don't like the fact that files belonging to the standard library are "compiled" to byte code on demand, as this happens within a process running both Python and native code that can crash unexpectedly. I would prefer to have all Python code pre-compiled, whether or not it helps to resolve the above situation.

Comment: If that's the case you should file a bug with the Python folks. But in principle,  the interpreter should recompile a module which has s damaged .pyc file the next time it is needed.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this by creating a 0-byte file `C:\Python27\Lib\hmac.pyc` and running `import hmac` in an interactive Python session. The file was recreated at a size of 5kb, and I did not get an error.

I have the information about 0-byte Python files from a colleague. The actual error I see is that I get an exception whenever running Python, and that reinstalling Python resolves the problem. Whether it is caused by corrupted .pyc files is not known. I will update my question.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17030047/2279059, corruption of Python files may be possible in Python 2.x, whereas Python 3.3 has mechanisms to prevent corruption from happening.

Comment: A snapshot of the Python folder contains a supposedly corrupted (1kb) `locale.pyc`. The file is supposed to be 49kb in size. Copying the "corrupted" file to a healthy Python installation does not reproduce the issue. Instead, the file is regenerated to 49kb in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the system `.pyc` files **read-only**, even for administrator. This should prevent Python from modyfing them unnecessarily.

If You're on Windows go to properties → security → edit, and deny all privileges for all groups.

Comment: Confirming that this prevents `.pyc` files from being created, and that Python still works without the `.pyc` (tested by deleting `locale.pyc`, denying write permission, running `import locale` and `dir(locale)` and verifying that `locale.pyc` does not exist).

However, I suspect that not having the byte code files can have an impact on performance, so I would like to make sure they are there before denying write access (which then also might be unnecessary).