# Make python reload() function read from .py instead of .pyc

Tags: python, reload, imp

I have written a rather large module which is automatically compiled into a .pyc file when I import it.

When I want to test features of the module in the interpreter, e.g., class methods, I use the `reload()` function from the `imp` package.

The problem is that it reloads the `.pyc` file, not the `.py` file.

For example I try a function in the interpreter, figure out that it is not working properly, I would make changes to the `.py` file. However, if I reload the module in the interpreter, it reloads the `.pyc` file so that the changes are not reflected in the interpreter. I would have to quit the interpreter, start it again and use `import` to load the module (and create the `.pyc` file from the `.py` file). Or alternatively I would have to delete the `.pyc` file each time.

Is there any better way? E.g., to make `reload()` prefer `.py` files over `.pyc` files?

Here is an except from the interpreter session that shows that `reload()` loads the `.pyc` file.

```
>>> reload(pdb)
<module 'pdb' from 'pdb.pyc'>
```

EDIT:
And even if I delete the `.pyc` file, another `.pyc` file will be created each time I use reload, so that I have to delete the `.pyc` file each time I use reload.

```
>>> reload(pdb)
<module 'pdb' from 'pdb.py'>
>>> reload(pdb)
<module 'pdb' from 'pdb.pyc'>
```

Comment: Delete the `.pyc` file?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my post, however, sometimes I need/want to open another interactive shell with this module to try something. And then a new pyc file will be created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid .pyc files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. here are things you can use [the `-B` command line option](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-B):

```
python -B
```

or use the [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment option](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE):

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

these make sure the `.pyc` files are not generated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using ipython, you can can do a shell command by prefixing it with `!`

So you could do

```
>>> !rm some_file.pyc
>>> reload(some_file)
```

Alternatively, you could define a quick function in your current shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> def reload(module_name):
...     os.system('rm ' + module_name + '.pyc')
...     reload(module_name)
...
```

and just call it whenever you want to reload your module.

Comment: I don't like iPython (it might be good for teaching, but not what I prefer for personal usage), I simply open python in a bash terminal. But thx.

Comment: @astrognocci, won't these two reload keywords clashed? I think it will call itself, instead of the system reload keyword.

Comment: and the second line in your function should be `'rm ' + module_name.__name__ + '.pyc'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove obsoleted *.pyc, because reload(module) does this automatically.

For this purpose I usually use something like:

```
    import module
    def reinit():
        try:
            reload(module)
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

        call_later(1, reinit)

    reinit()
```