# How to hide *pyc files in atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

Started using [Atom](https://atom.io/) for Python/Django development and would like to hide all the `*.pyc` files from sidebar.

How to configure it?

Comment: Maybe you could [avoid generating those files](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) in the first place?

Comment: @user694733 what's your preferred way of preventing .pyc files? Invoking `python` generates these by default. There are various approaches discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files

Comment: @Dilum Depends on use case. I use command line switch the most, but any of the methods you linked are useful.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The method for hiding files that you do not want showing up in the Tree View (which is what most people mean when they ask this question) depends on whether or not you've added the files to your `.gitignore`. If you have, then all you have to do is:

1. Open Settings
2. Scroll down the list on the left to find the `Tree View` package
3. Click on it to bring up the package-specific settings
4. Ensure `Hide Vcs Ignored Files` is checked

If you want to hide certain files in the Tree View whether you have a Git project open or not:

1. Open Settings
2. Add the file mask to the comma-separated list under `Ignored Names` (add `*.pyc` in your case)
3. Scroll down the list on the left to find the `Tree View` package
4. Click on it to bring up the package-specific settings
5. Ensure `Hide Ignored Names` is checked

Also note that when you add a file mask to the list of Ignored Names that files matching that mask will not show up in other parts of Atom like the `fuzzy-finder:find-file` (<kbd>Cmd+T</kbd> on OS X and <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> on Windows/Linux by default) command.

Comment: @Lee might also add that you want to close and reopen the project after you modify your `.gitignore` (that's what I had to do)

Comment: TIP : Toggle `Hide Vcs Ignored Files` by pressing `i` in tree-view.

Comment: @SurajThapar, @Lee , I think this _pressing_ `i` trick should actually be a part of the answer.

Answer (score 23):

I found [this](http://discuss.atom.io/t/way-to-make-pyc-files-disappear-from-tree-view/938) where it is said that you can toggle that in `Preferences`->`Tree View`->`Hide Ignored Names` and `Hide Vcs Ignored Files`.

**Edit:** The files to hide you have to specify first in `Preferences`->`Settings`->`Core Settings`->`Ignored Names`. This was described [here](http://discuss.atom.io/t/a-way-to-hide-the-ds-store-files-in-the-tree-view/1431).

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you try this, maybe that works? It would interest me too even though I do not have atom editor at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

In Atom 1.25.0 on Ubuntu I found this setting **Hide Vcs Ignored Files** under packages configuration: **Preferences -> Packages -> Tree View -> Settings**.

Also, pressing `I` while Tree View activated also works for me (@Suraj Thapar's comment).

Please note, you have 2 options here: Ignore file by **.gitignore** and ignore files by **Hide Ignored Names** which refers to **Ignored Names** core config settings.