# How do I hide a file by its extension in a Samba share?

Tags: security, samba, file-sharing

I have a folder where it would help me if certain file types were not accessible by its samba users.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should post on [sf], but check their help centre before posting.

Comment: It helped me hide pyc files programming with Python, but I understand your point.

Related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `smb.conf`, edit the share were you want to apply this and add this line to its properties:

```
veto files = /*.ext/
```

Where `ext` is the extension you want to block.

---

If you want to block **more than one** extension, do so like this:

```
veto files = /*.bmp/*.jpg/*.png/*.gif/
```

In this example I used some image extensions, but you can use any extension you want.

(You can even block specific files!)