# Avoid _pycache_ with iPython

Tags: python, caching, ipython

When using Python from the command line, one can suppress the output of the `_pycache_` directory using the command line option `-B`. Unfortunately, I wasn; able to find how to suppress this output in iPython.

What I have to do when I change a cached module with iPython is the following:

1. Exit from the interpreter
2. Remove the `_pycache_` folder manually
3. Enter the interpreter again

As you can imagine, this procedure is really annoying!

**Is there any way to suppress the `_pycache_` folder with iPython?**

Comment: import sys; sys.dont_write_bytecode = True from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files)

Comment: @JohnLund Actually this does not work with iPython apparently.

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment) Set the PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE environment variable, which should do the same thing.