# python import parent folder and child folder has the same name

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have the following structure, parts of the code are forks from other people and parts written by me

```
parentfolder/
       main.py
       utils.py
       fun1.py
       /childfolder/
             __init__.py
             main_child.py
             function.py
             /utils/
                 __init__.py
                 foo.py
```

Now in the `function.py`, I imported the `utils` module in the **parentfolder** following [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

(I use an interative python console binded with vim so the `__file__` solution does not work for me)

in my `main_child.py`, i imported `function`, as well `fun1` in the parent folder, which import `utils` in the parent folder
when i run `main_child.py`,  it complains

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'xxx' from 'utils' (parentfolder/childfolder/utils/__init__.py)
```

this error is caused in importing `fun1` since `fun1` import `utils` in the **parentfolder**, but now it seems that it only search the **filderfolder**

any solutions?

Comment: That is very confusing. It would be better to show imports in your code. And if you actually have this project structure, you might want to reconsider it: is there a reason for two `utils.py` files in different modules?

Comment: in the utils folder, it is foo.py, just edited

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245106/python-import-class-with-same-name-as-directory). TL;DR - better to rename package or module

Comment: Please show the actual imports in your files. It seems you want a package, not individual modules. You should not modify PYTHONPATH or sys.path in this case. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932498/dynamically-updating-the-pythonpath-prevents-pyc-update/39932711#39932711