# If a folder is read-only, where do the pyc files go?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyc

I am running `.py` files from a read-only network folder (via Python 2.7 on Windows). Are pyc files still generated? And if so, where do they go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents are generated by the compiler, but they are simply not saved (a loader may set an alternate [`__cached__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__cached__), but normally doesn't). The `.pyc` files are merely used to cache the result of the compilation. [`distutils.util.byte_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=pyc#distutils.util.byte_compile) has some documentation links for further details.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files for *inhibiting* pyc files.