# Is there any way to disable __pycache__ creation in yocto?

Tags: python-3.x, yocto

I'm building a yocto image (zeus) which requires python3, but the resulting file is quite large mainly due to the `__pycache__` directories which contain *.pyc and *.pyo files. These files are the python cache that, I think, can be regenerated during the first run if needed. Now my concerning is the final image size and I'd like to get rid of these files to save space.
Is there any python 3 recipe configuration I can change in a `.bbappend` to prevent creation of these files?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this advice " [How to avoid .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files) " and it stopped the creation of the `__pychache__` folder and contents.

Comment: To improve your answer, please link to the specific answer that helped you (you can do so by clicking Share underneath the answer and copying the path), rather than to the question, and provide additional details that will help others understand how you used that answer to solve the problem here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32081132)