# How do I avoid pollution of a .venv folder with files owned by root when running a script with root privileges?

Tags: python, linux, root, pyc, file-ownership

In virtual environment (created with poetry) I'm running a Python script regularly as current user via

```bash
poetry run ./script.py
```

or

```bash
.venv/bin/python3 script.py
```

From within this script I need to run another script with `root` privileges, which boils down to running that script via sudo:

```bash
sudo .venv/bin/python3 other_script.py
```

or

```bash
ssh root@localhost /<path>/<to>/.venv/bin/python3 /<path>/<to>/other_script.py
```

(I probably could also `setuid` the script but I'd prefer the `ssh`-way since I need it anyway. Also installing the virtual environment for `root` is not an option for me)

Running a script this way will create `__pycache__` folders and `.pyc` files owned by root and running `python3 -B` or setting [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files) will not create any bytecode files at all (which I'd also like to avoid).

On an abstract level - is there a nice way to run a Python3 script from an existing virtual environment owned by current user with `root` privileges without having to fiddle with `setuid` or missing `pyc` files?
Can I somehow tell Python (or the current environment) to create `pyc` files/folder with certain ownership or at a location owned by `root`?

Comment: when you create venv, you could set +s bit via chmod and all the files written into venv will inhering the initial user/group ?

Comment: That's interesting, didn't know that. Unfortunately this also requires manual fiddling and/or platform dependent knowledge (bad to automate), so I guess I stick to `python3 -B` for now

Comment: alternative would probably be to find out "why you need sudo" in the first place, doesn't sound like clean way either ..

Comment: In my case I'm working on a multi-purpose monitoring tool, which I don't want to run as `root`, but which has components (like package sniffing) which need `root` privileges to work. Those I run via `sudo` or `ssh root@remote` to achieve this. There are other options like `setuid`, giving the current user permissions, etc, but up to now I didn't find a way which doesn't involve manual user interaction every time the project structure changes.